# LCD image filter effect with GPUImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, imagefilter

What is the best way to gain an effect of LCD display similar to this app use - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/2bit-camera/id417598366

I need exactly 3 levels of black pixels: with 0.8 alfa, 0.4 and 0.0.

I know that I can resize image to desired amount of pixels, than iterate through all and replace colors to b/w with needed alfa values. But how to do it in more elegant way?

Comment: For the blocky nature of the image, start with the pixellation filter. Then you should be able to create a custom version of that with your own shader that reduces the colorspace (a posterization effect) and maps the reduced colorspace to your target colors. Now, if dithering is required, that can get tricky because dithering often requires in-order pixel operations and that's not practical to do in a shader.

Comment: Thanks Brad for reply. Not so easy as it seems to be... But what you think about approach author of that app use? Just your opinion.